# Calling TYPO3 plugin's method in TypoScript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

is it possible to call a method of a plugin from within TypoScript? I need to pass the output of a method to a TypoScript TEXT object.

This is how I imagine it (it is not a correct TypoScript code though):

```
lib.field_some_field.value.wrap < plugin.some_plugin.some_method
```

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**untested:**

```
# If you are using an USER Object
includeLibs.some_plugin = EXT:some_plugin/pi1/class.tx_some_plugin_pi1.php

lib.field_some_field_with_stdWrap.append < USER
lib.field_some_field_with_stdWrap.append {
  # you need includeLibs only, if you use an USER_INT Object
  includeLibs = EXT:some_plugin/pi1/class.tx_some_plugin_pi1.php
  userFunc = tx_some_plugin_pi1->some_method
}
```

But you need to set in localconf.php / via Install-Tool:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['userFuncClassPrefix'] = false
```

And **some_method** will be called tx_some_plugin_pi1->some_method($content, $conf), you cannot change the parameters!

**or**

If it is your extension, you could simply check for an conf-variable.

```
lib.field_some_field_with_stdWrap.append < plugin.some_plugin
lib.field_some_field_with_stdWrap.append.useMethod = some_method
```

Now check in your main() method for $conf['useMethod'].